# Using Distinct Max Partition in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MAX(pb.revision) OVER (PARTITION BY pb.batch) AS REVNO, 
    pb.lot, pb.batch
FROM 
    db1 ps
INNER JOIN 
    db2 pb ON ps.Title = pb.Lot
WHERE 
    pb.proposalsubmitted IS NOT NULL 
    AND PS.Contract LIKE 'CLS' 
    AND BATCH <> 6
GROUP BY 
    pb.lot, pb.batch, pb.revision
ORDER BY 
    pb.lot
```

Above is my code snippet - I'm trying to retrieve the Max Revision number per batch. There can be multiple batches per LOT number. An added problem is that this database was setup in SharePoint at one time and the batch column is actually a `VARCHAR` and not `Integer`. I'm not sure if that is what the issue is because every time I do a pull I end up with:

[image: Results from query]

The actual batch numbers and corresponding revisions are here:

[image: Real batch and Lot numbers]

Thanks guys - it maybe a fundamental issue on my part or a misunderstanding of the over() partition by

Comment: You say it was setup in Sharepoint at one point, can you not do an Alter Table Alter Column and switch it to an integer type now if it's no longer related to Sharepoint?

Comment: I'm pulling things in views. I'm a report writer not the administrator. I was trying to avoid going to the admin and asking them to change the column.

Comment: Fair enough, are you trying to find the max revision by batch for each lot number or for the whole batch? If you want it by batch for each lot number you need to add the lot to your partition list.

MAX(pb.revision) OVER (PARTITION BY pb.batch,pb.lot) AS REVNO,

Comment: **DISTINCT** MAX(pb.revision) OVER PARTITION BY pb.batch, **pb.lot**) AS RevNo worked out. Thanks Anthony. If you want to post an answer i'll give you the upvote.

Comment: That's because of your grouping statement. What you really want isn't windowed aggregation (this is intended to apply aggregated values to all rows). You want to change your where clause and add: AND pb.revision = (SELECT MAX(_pb.revision) FROM db2 as _pb where pb.lot = _pb.lot AND pb.batch = _pb.batch)

Comment: If I add that to the where clause I can remove it from the select statement? I want to return these values and use them to SUM and COUNT

Comment: Yes, if you add it to the where clause you can remove it from the select and also get rid of your grouping because you are filtering to get only the rows that meet your criteria.